# OpenCV in Java: how can I output all kind of symbols? (Chinese, Japanese, Accents, etc...)

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

I'm doing a project in Android Studio with OpenCV using Object Detection. The idea behind my project is to translate the name of a selected object, in a language that the user can choose.
My problem is that when I do
`Imgproc.putText(frame, testo, box.tl(), Core.FONT_ITALIC, 2, new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3);`
(where "testo" is the translated name) in a language with specific symbols (like Chinese or Japanese, or simply with accents) it just gives me "???" as output.
I saw that there is a module called FreeType, but I didn't get if is just usable in C++ or also in Java.
Does anyone know what can I do? Or if maybe there are other modules that I can use?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV's built-in fonts are limited.

You need to build OpenCV with [support for `freetype/harfbuzz`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html). It's in `opencv_contrib`. I don't know how much trouble that'll be for android. You need to build freetype and harfbuzz too, or find binaries.

Then the `cv::freetype::putText` function supports "proper" fonts, which means it also supports more unicode characters.

That should be usable from Java as well... it's certainly usable from Python, and both are generated bindings.